# Combine 2 Columns in mysql (Tried union already)

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT  
`b`.`city_name` as `city_name`
        ,`a`.`address_name` as `address_name`
    ,`b`.`country_id` AS `country_id`
    ,`b`.`city_id` AS `city_id`
    ,`a`.`address_id` AS `address_id`
    FROM (
    `addresses` `a` INNER JOIN `cities` `b` ON ((`a`.`country_id` = `b`.`country_id`))
    )
```

Result

```
city_name   address_name       country_id city_id address_id
Doha        Al Sadd                     1       1          1
Al Khor     Al Sadd                     1       2          1
Doha        Al Duhail                   1       1          2
Al Khor     Al Duhail                   1       2          2
Doha        Al Asmakh                   1       1          3
Al Khor     Al Asmakh                   1       2          3
Doha        Al Khraiteyat               1       1          4
Al Khor     Al Khraiteyat               1       2          4
Doha        Umm Salal Mohammad          1       1          5
Al Khor     Umm Salal Mohammad          1       2          5
Doha        The Pearl                   1       1          6
AlKhor      The Pearl                   1       2          6
Doha        Salwa Road                  1       1          7
Al Khor     Salwa Road                  1       2          7
Doha        Ein Khaled                  1       1          8
Al Khor     Ein Khaled                  1       2          8
Doha        Sumaysimah                  1       1          9
Al Khor     Sumaysimah                  1       2          9
Doha        Fereej Bin Mahmoud          1       1         10
Al Khor     Fereej Bin Mahmoud          1       2         10
Doha        Al Najma                    1       1         11
Al Khor     Al Najma                    1       2         11
Doha        Al Gharrafa                 1       1         12
```

I've tried the mysql code above. I want to combine city and address in one column. 
So it should be.

```
CITY_ADDRESS
-Al Sadd
-Al Duhail
-Al Asmakh
-Doha
-Al Khor
..and so on...
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try: `concat_ws( ' - ', b.city_name, a.address_name ) as city_address`?

Comment: This will just concatenate it, i need to put them all in distinct rows

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT city_name place FROM my_table UNION SELECT DISTINCT address_name  FROM my_table;`

Answer (score 0):

try the `concat` function
Example:

```
select concat(column1,column2) as merged_column from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using || to concatenate strings in the select query. Here's an example for syntax.

select city_name||'-'||address as city_address
from table1,table2

This is what we do in oracle. Alternatively you could try this.

select concat(city_name,address) as city_address from table1,table2.

Check the below link for more details:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will just concatenate it, i need to put them all in distinct rows

Comment: you could use distinct to work with select.                                               select distinct concat(city_name,address) as city_address from table1,table2. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, it will just bind the two values. I need to be like this: CITY_ADDRESS
-Al Sadd
-Al Duhail
-Al Asmakh
-Doha
-Al Khor
..and so on...